# Using datepicker-ui in WordPress but the value is Null everytime

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, datepicker

My datepicker works, at first! But if i'm checking the value of the input (with the datepicker) the value always is Null. The right value is displaying and an alert shows the right date. But in my php file i just retrieve null

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="flex-grid fg-step-1">
        <div class="col col-medium-6 col-small-12 ">
            <p style="margin-bottom: 20px;">Date Start</p>
            <input type="text" id="dateStart" name="dateStart" class="datepicker"> 
        </div>

        <div class="col col-medium-6 col-small-12 ">
            <p style="margin-bottom: 20px;">Date End</p>
            <input type="text" id="dateEnd" name="dateEnd" class="datepicker">
        </div>

    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="main_btn"">
</form>
```

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('#dateEnd').prop('disabled', true);

    jQuery( '#dateStart' ).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true, 
        changeYear: true,
        showAnim: "slideDown",
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        minDate: 0,
        onSelect: function(selectedDate){
            jQuery('#dateEnd').datepicker('option', 'minDate', selectedDate);
            jQuery('#dateEnd').prop('disabled', false);
            alert(selectedDate);
        }
    });

    jQuery( '#dateEnd' ).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true, 
        changeYear: true,
        showAnim: "slideDown",
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        onSelect: function(selectedDate){
            alert(selectedDate);
        }
    });
})
```

```
<?php
if ( $_POST['dateStart'] == Null ) {
                $dateStart             = false;
                $in_date_start          = "";
            } else {
                $in_date_start = $_POST['dateStart'];
            }
if ( $_POST['dateEnd'] == Null) {
                $dateEnd           = false;
                $in_date_end          = "";
            } else {
                $in_date_end = $_POST['dateEnd'];
            }
?>
```

The Problem is, that we are using WordPress and using our own Theme. I need a solution for retrieving the selectedDate in my php-code

Answer (score 0):

You can use hidden field : 
1) get date and set in hidden field {with JS} and retrieve date from hidden field in php { at form submission }

Comment: i entered the date of 2019-04-30 but getting a value of 1988 from the hidden input

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mfDcs5h1CmILmAzeUHOzr1IqyERNDdxQ

please check this, this is working fine at my Local server

Comment: i wrote exatly the same, but don't retrieve the right value. If i'm using the google chrome def-tools i found the right value of the hidden input (for example 2019-04-30) in the properties with name "defaultValue" but if i use console.log(<?php echo $_POST['hidd']); i'm getting -1998. And i dont know why. WordPress is a pain in the ass

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TAmnaAAjKEYjwUZkYN7F9Q4Xcq7EyXuB

Please convert file in php and save in your theme (this is page template )